# Allow only one value in jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I followed this tutorial to to achieve hotmail-style items but I want one more thing,
I want to allow the users to select only one value

[How to Use the jQuery UI Autocomplete Widget](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/)

The demo [page](http://www.danwellman.co.uk/demos/autocomplete.html)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You shouold show how you have attempted to modify the `select:` and `change:` yourself here.  If you did not know that is where the change need lies, you are further behind in the learning curve and should study up on the autocomplete more.

Comment: ... And you should post your code here. If your demo site goes down the question will be useless to people having the same problem.

Comment: my problem was solved. i changed in **select:**, and before insert new span, i was remove all existing sapn like this.
$("#<%=divP.ClientID%> span").remove(); after this line use span.insertBefore("#<%=tbO.ClientID%>"); to insert current selected item. 
thanks Mark and Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was solved. 
i changed in

```
select:,
```

and before insert new span, i was remove all existing sapn like this.

```
$("#<%=divP.ClientID%> span").remove();
```

after this line use

```
span.insertBefore("#<%=tbO.ClientID%>");
```

to insert current selected item.